# How to filter and get only the specific array from list mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a nodejs application with MongoDB as database.

I wanted to retrieve only the array having `"is_active" : "true"`

```
{
  "response": "206",
  "dev_toast": {
    "_id": "55eab3cb358c513439c3ce5d",
    "flat_tenant": [
      {
        "tenant_id": null,
        "is_active": "false",
        "_id": "55eac5db5e1ddb87104a7865"
      },
      {
        "tenant_id": {
          "_id": "geo@gmail.com",
          "user_first_name": "Geo",
          "user_last_name": "Joy",
          "user_profile_pic": "sampleProfile.jpg",
          "user_phone": "332534",
          "user_permanent_address": "#14th Main"
        },
        "is_active": "true",
        "_id": "55eac6065e1ddb87104a7866"
      },
      {
        "tenant_id": null,
        "is_active": "false",
        "_id": "55ead263232fe9585a86bb7f"
      }
    ]
  },
  "pub_toast": "we found 3 flats."
}
```

Comment: But, there is not array.

Comment: Works the same way :)

Comment: In Mongoose: `Name_of_model.find({"dev_toast.flat_tenant.is_active": "true"}, function(err, documents) {})`. Note in your document dump your booleans are strings so I made them strings in this query

Comment: i used
flats.find({ $and: [ { building_id: building_id }, { _id: flat_id },{ "flat_tenant.is_active" : "true"} ] },

but still getting all the 3 objects.

I want to get on "is_aactive": "true"